# Event Listener is not calling function

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have an HTML/CSS file with a form and I'm trying to add an event listener to the button of the form.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ... all css files here
</head>


<body class="registrationFormBody"> 
    <section class="sectionForms">

        <div class="serviceProviderRegistrationFormDiv">
            <form class="serviceProviderRegistrationForm">
                .... labels and inputs
                <button id="verifyProviderAddress" type="button" value="ProviderAddress">Verify</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script type="module" src="public\js\Geocode.js"></script>
</html>
```

I also have my Geocode file that correctly selects the button:

```
let buttonVerifyProviderAddress = document.getElementById("verifyProviderAddress");

buttonVerifyProviderAddress.addEventListener("click", () => onClickVerifyAddress());

function onClickVerifyAddress()
{
    window.alert("I'm in");
    console.log("Verifying");
}
```

I checked on the debugger, the event listener is there:

[image]

But it's not calling it. When I click nothing happens. No console.log, no window alert.
What am I doing wrong?

I've tried already change the way of adding the listener:

```
buttonVerifyProviderAddress.addEventListener("click",()=>{console.log("Hey")});
buttonVerifyProviderAddress.onclick = ()=>{console.log("Ola");};
```

But nothing happens.
I think something is preventing the event listener to actually call, but what? Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I added the code you posted to a jsfiddle (online editor) and it works as expected. There must be an issue with something you haven't posted. If you strict out everything except what you posted does it work? - https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/0aeghLnx/#&togetherjs=5uDRoJIKwd

Comment: Maybe you declared `buttonVerifyProviderAddress` wrong because the code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within the script tag. It has a type of module, can you try to remove the type attribute from the script tag and see if it works?